# Why login redirect is not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to login though API. My code is like below.

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $response = Http::post('http://moretext/login', [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ]);

    $session_token = str_replace("Bearer ", "", $response->json()['access_token']);  // I am getting Token here

    if ($session_token) {
        Session::put('SesTok', $session_token);
        return redirect('/dashboard');   //This redirect is not working.
    } else {
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Login is not successful.');
    }
}
```

I have below the code in route.php file.

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: /Dashboard route is auth protected? Maybe you are not starting session on the server, only is authenticated in remote serve.

Comment: Another question, the Http::post('http://moretext/login.... is calling other server or is the same that you are working?

Answer (score 0):

there's no redirect throw apis
api except response json

if you want to redirect don't call as api

do in web routes and it will work fine